# Undefined index. Server Error or coding problem?

Tags: php

i tried to do some practise about form actions and inputs and copy-paste a piece of codes but i got  Undefined index: fname and Undefined index: age. The codes were taken from very popular php tutorial website, there should not be any problem with them but submitting them anyway.Is this server error or something like that?

```
          <form action="posting.php" method="post">
          Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
          Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
          <input type="submit" />
          </form>
          <?php

          echo $_POST["fname"];
          echo $_POST["age"];

          ?>
```

Comment: Just because a website is popular doesn't mean its tutorials are best practice or up-to-date. You can find tutorials written 10 years ago that won't even run on a modern version of PHP.

Comment: Good job having error reporting enabled though, seems to be absent from most new developer setups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `$_POST` is getting information before you try to read from it. There are a variety of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
<form action="posting.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        echo $_POST["fname"];
        echo $_POST["age"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I saw some coding that input html tag was used after PHP codes. Is that the reason to code like that, I mean to prevent reading empty input?

Comment: The order of the form and PHP code doesn't matter in terms of the logic of the form, and will only effect the order that the form and the output of the code are displayed on the screen.

Comment: Last question:)why did the code jump to PHP if the browser knows that input is empty. I mean according to my experience(Java), code cannot jump to other line without executing them in order. Why do we need extra check(if statement)?

Comment: The PHP is not executed on the web page - it's executed by the server before the page is spat out to the user. Only after a user fills out the form and sends it back to the server is any `$_POST` data visible to the server. Before that, the `$_POST` variable is empty, and attempting to print anything from it will result in the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

Until that form is submitted, `$_POST` is empty and trying to read anything out of it will result in such a notice.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['age'])) {
    echo $_POST['fname']; 
    echo $_POST['age'];
}
```

Comment: Got another tip for you Dan :) `isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['age'])`